# Rootkit attack by inserting new binary formats

Tags: kernel, rootkit

Some rootkits attack works by inserting a new binary format in the
formats list and supplying the kernel with a malicious
handler that returns the error code ENOEXEC each time it is
invoked. Since the new handler is inserted at the head of the
formats list, the malicious handler is executed each time a
new process is executed.The size of the list is constant after the system
starts, and changes only when a new binary format is
installed. As this attack inserts a new binary format it
changes the length of the formats list.
I've read this in an article. I wanna know is this true in kernel 3, too? If yes how can I check length of formats list?
I found this struct in kernel 3.11.4:

```
 /*
  * This structuredefines the functions that are used to load the binary formats that
  * linux accepts.
  */
  struct linux_binfmt {
          struct list_head lh;
          struct module *module;
          int (*load_binary)(struct linux_binprm *);
          int (*load_shlib)(struct file *);
          int (*core_dump)(struct coredump_params *cprm);
          unsigned long min_coredump;     /* minimal dump size */
  };
```

Is `lh` list that refered `formats list`?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how to count formats in kernel 3 but if your pc is attacked by rootkit, despite knowing the count of formats u cannot do anything. The article which u read this proposes method of detection of rootkit attack while it tries to add a new format (invariant violation).